# JSON Parsing in Swift

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I was doing the [JSON Parsing in Swift tutorial by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial).

While using `DataManager.getTopAppsDataFromAppsWithSuccess` in `viewDidLoad()`, Its unable to print out the array when its outside the `DataManager` block.

Does someone know how to get the array values outside that block ?

Code :

```
var apps = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
  DataManager.getTopAppsDataFromAppsWithSuccess { (ByodData) -> Void in
    let json = JSON(data: ByodData)
       if let appArray = json.array{
        for appDict in appArray {
          var appName: String = appDict["name"].stringValue
          self.apps.append(appName)
         }
      }
  println(self.apps)
}
```

Input JSON:

```
[
   {
       "id":1,
       "name":"AdobeReader",
       "url":"comp2014group1.herokuapp.com/apps/1.json";
   },
   {
       "id":2,
       "name":"BBCiPlayer",
       "url":"comp2014group1.herokuapp.com/apps/2.json";
   },
   {
       "id":3,
       "name":"BBCNews",
       "url":"comp2014group1.herokuapp.com/apps/3.json";
   },
   {
       "id":4,
       "name":"BBCWeather",
       "url":"comp2014group1.herokuapp.com/apps/4.json";
   }
]
```

Output :

```
[]
```

Comment: Can you also specify your json data you are loading ?

Comment: The JSON Data is as follows :                                        [{"id":1,"name":"AdobeReader","url":"https://comp2014group1.herokuapp.com/apps/1.json"},{"id":2,"name":"BBCiPlayer","url":"https://comp2014group1.herokuapp.com/apps/2.json"},{"id":3,"name":"BBCNews","url":"https://comp2014group1.herokuapp.com/apps/3.json"},{"id":4,"name":"BBCWeather","url":"https://comp2014group1.herokuapp.com/apps/4.json"}]

Comment: You should have added it to the question text for more readability

Comment: So Is there any way to get around this, basically getting the app names and displaying them in a UIPicker ?

Comment: @skyline75489 is right you are using the `println` statement too soon for the data to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This function `getTopAppsDataFromAppsWithSuccess` seems to be an async one, which will not block execution. Thus the `println(self.apps)` is immediately executed before the data is actually retrieved.

The JSON data should be OK. Just don't try to print it like that. You can use the JSON data after it's ready.

Comment: I was wanting to display the array of apps on a UIPickerView but when I use the self.apps I get a blank picker. Is there anyway I can pull the array from the DataManager block

Comment: You can use `reloadAllComponents` function of UIPickerView in the block to refresh the picker view using the data retrieved. However, `viewDidLoad` may not be the perfect place to do this. Because `viewDidLoad` is called before the view is loaded. The picker view itself may not be ready when you try to refresh it.

Comment: So Is there any way to get around this, basically getting the app names and displaying them in a UIPicker ?

Comment: The easiest way to do this will be using sync method, which might cause a little lagging. But the data you are dealing with doesn't seem to be very large. So it should be OK.